# Read non alphabetic character using pandas from excel

Tags: pandas, character-encoding, data-processing, file-encodings, non-alphanumeric

I am trying to read [this file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cpg91D3aB7bo6tUlajoHWgJ8PFVhFJjZTKvJCeIUCpg/edit?usp=sharing) using pandas in UTF-8 encoding.

English alphabetic characters are read properly but those characters which are not English alphabet are not read properly. I tried reading by changing encoding from `utf8` to `cp1252`, `ASCII` but nothing worked for me.

For more detail see the image. 
[image: UTF8 encoded]

[image: ascii encoded]

Comment: your dataset deny the access can you open the access or provide the head for your dataframe

Comment: Hi Darknight,
It's open now.

Comment: try this      df=pd.read_excel(u"Translate.xlsx", encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding())

Comment: It doesn't work. Output is same.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> file = "D:\\Python\\SO3\\data\\62015078.xlsx"
>>> data = pd.read_excel(file,encoding='utf8')
>>> data.en
0     Release note
1    Sales package
2        Schematic
3         Software
4        Statistic
5            Video
Name: en, dtype: object
>>> data.ja
0    リリースノート
1    販売パッケージ
2        回路図
3     ソフトウェア
4         統計
5         動画
Name: ja, dtype: object
>>> data.zh
0    版本说明
1     销售包
2     示意图
3      软件
4      统计
5      视频
Name: zh, dtype: object
```

The code snippet works. The `�` character is *Replacement Character* (`U+FFFD`). You need to set proper console / terminal font:

[image: output with proper terminal font]

The same window with a common console font:

[image: output with improper terminal font]

Comment: It appears that `pd.read_excel` works independently  on supplied `encoding`, for instance using `data = pd.read_excel(file,encoding='none')` or even `data = pd.read_excel(file)`.